# Can humans eat a greater variety of things than other omnivores?

Tags: human-biology, diet

One thing that I've always noted is that humans seem able to eat just about anything that isn't toxic (and many things that are). Even when compared to other omnivores, I have the impression that humans are capable of eating far more things without harm. Is this true?

Comment: I don't know about that.  My dog seems to eat anything I would (of course I don't give him things like chocolate, but he would eat it if I did), plus many things I would not, such as horse manure, hoof trimmings, long-dead critter bones...

Comment: Maybe so, but you COULD eat those things (disgusting, but that's all). On the other hand, your dog would actually get sick, and possibly die, from eating things such as; onion, garlic, chives, chocolate, macademia nuts, avocado, xylitol (sweetener), cherries, grapes/raisins... You get my point?

Comment: No, because even if I (as a typical human) could force myself to swallow many of the things that a dog happily eats, I would actually get sick, and possibly die, from eating them.  Sure, humans can safely eat some things that dogs can't, just as dogs can safely eat some things humans can't, but that is not saying that humans can safely eat more things.

Comment: @jamesqf Really? I know there are many things a dog eats that I would not like to eat, but I've not thought about them being "inedible" for me. Do you have a few examples?